# two column index overflow

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I have a book, with an index. In the preamble I'm using `\makeindex` and then, at the end of the book, I'm saying `\printindex`. Works fine and prints the index in two columns. However, the first column of the first index page flows way below the bottom border of the page. See the picture:

[image]

I'm seeing this in log:

```
Overfull \vbox (90.07774pt too high) has occurred while
\output is active [220] [221] [222])
```

Comment: Can you see anything strange in the `.ind` file? What options are you passing for making the index?

Comment: @egreg nope, nothing strange there.. I'm not passing any options, just `\makeindex`

Comment: Sorry, but I've never seen something like this; a minimal example is needed, but I know it may be difficult.

Comment: @egreg see my own answer... I fixed the problem but maybe you can shed some light on the real cause of it.. thanks.

Comment: @yegor256 -- and what was the fix that restored the first column to the desired length?

Comment: @barbarabeeton see my answer below

Comment: @yegor256 -- thanks.  (i've been working on a document about how to deal with problems in indexing (ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/author-info/documentation/howto/0index-notes.pdf) and wanted to see if this was a "candidate problem"  i think it isn't, but the information is interesting and potentially useful anyhow.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by moving `\setlength{\topskip}{0mm}` from document body into preamble. Have no idea why, but this was the problem.

Comment: You shouldn't set `\topskip` to 0 to begin with